# Submit button not showing in revolution slider

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having a form on the revolution slider but my submit button is not showing yet its there in the form code

```
h2.wpb_heading.wpb_revslider_heading { display: none; }

.content-wrapper {padding:0px;}
.navbar-wrapper{padding:0px;}

.wpcf7 {
  padding: 45px 45px 5px 45px !important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 500px;
  height:600px;
}

.wpcf7 p {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#formContainer &gt;
h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.wpcf7 input[type="text"],
.wpcf7 input[type="email"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
}

.left {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 48%;
  float: right;
}

.wpcf7-submit {
  background-color: rgb(250, 104, 57);
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Contact form 7 code

```
<label> Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Subject
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label> Your Message
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Send"]
```

You can see what is happening here also what is the best way of getting this form to be responsive on a revolution slider as when I collapse it it does not display way on mobile.

Url

http://landingpage.solitudesoftware.co.uk/

Image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeKwR.jpg

Comment: Your form is just to large to fit inside the given area. Reduce your `textarea` - if you inspect that form element and find `p label .wpcf7-form-control-wrap textarea` in the DOM, change the attribute value for `rows` to `5` instead of `10` (e.g: `rows="5"`) and you'll be able to see it easily. Or just declare the following rule: `textarea.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-textarea {
    max-height: 120px;
}`

Comment: thanks that was it I actually removed the message box and it showed no problem